# Create new ClassLoader to reload Class

Tags: java, class, build

I want to create a new `ClassLoader` everytime my method is called.

So I can reload a `class` without exiting my program.

A way how I can update a `class` loaded by `ClassLoader` would also be a solution.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I load a JavaCompiler sourcecode compiled class with loadClass("string"), then I run this class with JUnitCore. After that I edit the source code in the *.java, compile it with the JavaCompiler and want to reload it again.

Comment: Interesting question for a good use case.  +1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a good explained answer here:

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/reloadclass.html

The important thing is to have two binary folders, in my case:
one for the testcases and one for the program source.

Quote:

```
URL[] urls = null;
try {
    // Convert the file object to a URL
    File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")
        +File.separator+"dir"+File.separator);
    URL url = dir.toURL();        // file:/c:/almanac1.4/examples/
    urls = new URL[]{url};
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
}

try {
    // Create a new class loader with the directory
    ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

    // Load in the class
    Class cls = cl.loadClass("MyReloadableClassImpl");
```

Comment: Just to add - this solution works only if your reloaded class doesn't have any method deletion/new class reference. The problem with this approach is that if someone fogets to add dependent classes first, this might create NoClassDefFoundError. The best thing is to reload all classes without fully stoppping the application.

Comment: Link in answer is dead.

Answer (score 6):

saw this ?   [ClassLoader Load / Reload Example](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html#example)

I think this blog can satisfy your requirement.